# PF BlockUI - keep gif animating after oncomplete

Tags: ajax, animation, primefaces, blockui

I have a commandButton, which redirects to a page with a form. On the commandButton action I call a method which loads data from a DB to fill this form, and redirects to it's page. Loading takes about 5-10 seconds.
On the commandButton onstart method I call show() on the blockUI, and if I call hide() when oncomplete occurs, it hides the animated gif before data load operation and page redirection, therefore it's no use for it. Also, when I decide not to call hide, so I can see it while data loads, it stops animating (I guess) when ajax complete occurs. 
How can I make the gif animate during data load?

Comment: Hi, see [ask]... Show what code you have so we can comment on that instead of 'guessing' or writing a complete solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use blockUI with h:graphicImage content to display a loader.

```
<p:blockUI id="blockUI" block="contentToBlock" widgetVar="loader">
    LOADING<br/>
    <h:graphicImage library="images/" name="loader.gif" height="60px" width="60px"/>
</p:blockUI>
```

In this case, before redirecting to another page the gif stopped animating after ajax request completed, and it freezed during data load.

```
<p:commandButton value="Redirect" id="someID" ajax="false" 
                        onclick="PF('loader').show()" 
                        action="#{redirectToNextPageAndLoadDataAction()}"/>
```

Using ajax=false paired with onclick makes it work like I wanted, the animated gif can be seen until page redirection, though I never hide it this way, so when you use you browser to get back to the previous page, the gif is still open there, and the UI is blocked, which is not too good, but I'm working on it.

Update: this last error only happens in Firefox